# How can I set a different value to an element style property when the element is inside a ol or ul tags?

Tags: css

I'm not sure the title is phrased clearly so I'll try explaining here.
In the `.Note` class, margin-left set to `20px`.

I want that when I apply this class inside `<ol>` or `<ul>`, margin-left will be set to `0px` - only inside these tags not anywhere else.

Is that possible?

This is the CSS and html sample:

```css
.Note
{
 width: 98%;
 height: 70px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font: 16px "Segoe UI";
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 background-position: 10px 10px;
 padding-left: 80px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

div.Note
{
 background-image: url("../Images/note.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ol>
            <li>
                <p>[Replace with your text].</p>
                <div class="Note">This is my note.</div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <p>[Replace with your text].</p>
             </li>
        </ol>
```

You can see that the div is indented `20px` inside `<li>`. I want it to be `0px`, while keeping `.Note {margin-left: 20px;}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ul .Note, ol .Note {
  /* Selects all elements with the Note class within an <ol> or an <ul> */
}

ul > .Note, ol > .Note {
  /* Selects all elements with the Note class IMMEDIATELY within an <ol> or an <ul> */
}
```

Does this solve your problem? because if it does, you should really check out [basic css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) before you try something serious with css.

Comment: Thanks @wordbug I can see how this would work. The thing is that I have about 10 different variants besides `.Note`. Would that mean I will need to create `ul.[Variant], ol.[Variant]` for each variant?

Comment: @TechWriter Generally, yes. That's one thing css preprocessors can help with, but I don't recommend you to try them until you've mastered css. Note, though, that there should be a space between the `ul` and the `variant` if you want to select elements within, instead of the `ul` element itself.

Comment: @TechWriter In theory you can use the [:matches()](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/) pseudo-class if you want to apply the same exact style to those elements, but it's [badly supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo)